# Embeddings model: out of sample prediction with Keras for Collaborative Filtering

Tags: keras, recommender-system, embeddings

I have been trying to play with an example on [Collaborative Filtering for Movie Recommendations (keras.io)](https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/collaborative_filtering_movielens/), which builds embedding layers for movies and users.
Now, in a regular pre-trained word- and doc-embeddings we can use them to get embedding vectors for new text inputs.
However, I could not find how to do that in Keras for an out-of-sample user (vector of movie ratings for the same movies), as model.predict methods expect the input to be a combination of user id and movie id.
Is this true or and if it is, are there any workarounds/methods to deal with out-of-sample prediction, if I want to use an embedding model?

Comment: By out-of-sample, do you mean a situation where you're trying to make predictions for a new user? If so, this is essentially the cold-start problem -- there's a few possible methods to address that [here][https://kojinoshiba.com/recsys-cold-start/]. Concretely, I'm not sure that `keras.layers.Embedding` supports out-of-sample lookup, so you may need to subclass the Keras base layer, or find a pre-existing implementation.